# Start/stop computer applications using Android device

Tags: android, remote-access

Are there any pre-defined classes in Android SDK which can be used to connect to external system, and start/stop their applications?

Like let us connect an Android mobile with a computer using Cable/Bluetooth. Now using an app in the android device, I want to start some of the applications like Notepad++ etc in the Computer.

Is there any way to do this? I'm stuck even to get a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any pre-defined classes in Android SDK which can be used to
>   connect to external system, and start/stop their applications?

Predefined classes? No. None that I know of.

But what you are looking to do can be achieved by using **[Virtual Network Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)**.

**[Android VNC Viewer](https://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/)** is the best example you can get if you are looking to control your computer with your Android device.

And best of all, this awesome project is totally open source. So you can view and checkout the **[source code](https://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/source/checkout)** to understand the working.

Comment: Thanks. But are there a bit simpler sources around? This is quite heavy to start learning from its source.

Comment: I am sorry. But when I started with VNC this is all I got. I understand that it's a little heavy. But so is the domain that you are stepping into.

Comment: You are welcome! All the best ahead! :)